# Highcharts Drilldown from Stacked Column chart to Stacked Area Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I've got to a point with this chart where I have a stacked column chart drilling down to a stacked area chart - the big issue has been maintaining the colours for the different layers of data in each stack.  That is now sorted but I have a further issue.

In the stacked Area chart I can see the markers for each point but I can't get the area to fill.  Not sure why as the markers indicate the right points from the data.

Please help.

Here is the code

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        },
        area: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            colorByPoint: true,
            colors: ['#2B6E97','#4184AD','#589BC4','#6FB2DB','#86C9F2']
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/robdwright/uxo2edzu/53/

Thanks
Rob

Comment: The problem is having multiple values for the same x-value. For example: `[ [8, 13.77],  [8, 2.74], ... ]` -> there should be only one point for `8`.

Comment: @PawełFus I told him that, but even when there is only one point per category the points appear scattered.

Comment: Then simply remove `colorByPoint` option. Highcharts won't render spline with multiple colors until someone include plugin for it. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/uxo2edzu/56/

Comment: Thanks for looking at this both of you.  The issue is when I'm try to create an area stack within the drilldown, that;s what is producing several points per 8, 9 ....... As you mentioned Raeen I think its the structure of the data that needs to change